# Linked list data edit deletes entire list

Tags: c++, linked-list

My class is asking for a program that is capable of inserting projects (this task is working) and giving an evaluation back to them. The problem is when I **try to give an evaluation**, the program just **deletes the whole list**, and I don’t know why. Here is the evaluation function:

```
No * evaluate(No * head){
    int projectID;

    cout<<"What is the ID?\n";
    cin >> projectID;

    while (head != NULL)
    {
        if (head->ID == projectID){
            int evaluation;
            cout<<"Please insert the evaluation \n";
            cin >> evaluation;
            head->evaluation = evaluation;
        }
        head = head->next;
    }

    return head;
}
```

This is my struct:

```
typedef struct dados {
    int ID;
    int evaluation;
    struct dados *next; //pointer to next node
}No;
```

To call the function I use:

```
int main(){
    No * ll = NULL;

    while (true){
        int ID;
        cout << "Please insert the ID \n";
        cin >> ID;

        ll = insertFront(id);
        ll = evaluate(head);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code calling the function, and how you use the return value. If for example you write it back to your head node outside, you'll lose the list (since the return value is always null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your problem:

The problem is that you execute your while loop in your evaluation function until head reaches NULL:

```
while (head != NULL)
```

Then, you return from your evaluation function after exiting the while loop (so head is now NULL) and you return head:

```
   return head;   // <== will always return NULL
```

And finally you set this in your list pointer in main:

```
    ll = evaluate(head);  // ll will be null
```

### The solution:

It's not fully clear to me if `evaluate()` shall return the pointer to the list, or the pointer to the node found.

If it's to the node found, the easiest way would be to return from the function as soon as you've updated the node:

```
   ... 
   if (head->ID == projectID){
      ... (as before) 
      return head;   <<=== add this line 
   }
```

If it's to the begin of the list, then you just have to save `head` in a temporary valiable, at the beginning of your function, and return this temporary variable instead of `head`.

```
No * evaluate(No * head)
{
    No *tmp = head;   // no new !  It's a pointer, just take the value of the head
    ...  // as before
    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        if (tmp->ID == projectID){
             int evaluation;
             cout<<"Please insert the evaluation\n";
             cin >> evaluation;
             tmp->evaluation = evaluation;
             return head;  // We return the full list (head) 
        }
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    cout <<"Project not found\n";
    return head;
}
```

Comment: You are right, do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: I add this on my evaluation code: `No * temp = new No; temp = head;` I replace all the `head` in the function with `temp` and I did `return temp`, and still does't work.

Comment: I already have this this line `return head;` I and just don´t work. By the way thank you for all.

Comment: @user3199227 either you save head into tmp, move through the heads, and return tmp,  or you copy head to tmp, move through the tmps and return head.   I've edited to clarify.